# Delay in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application object creation

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, interop

I've one windows forms application developed in VB.NET which is using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application to read a doc file.

But the application is slow and on debugging its found that delay is with this line
`Dim obj As Word.Application = New Word.Application`

Could you please tell me is there any fix without code change.

Comment: Thatcould be 'normal', because unlike a typical small object (either .NET or COM/ActiveX) you are starting a large application. Is it taking any longer than starting tWord manually, for example? If it isn't, a number of things can slow down Word, e.g. it can't find files such as Normal.dotm in the locations it expects. If your application is using New Word.Application frequently (e.g. while processing a loop), then you probably need to restructure so that you only use New (or CreateObject) once and re-use the object that it creates, then Quit when your program terminates.

Comment: [Interop.Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word?view=word-pia) is slow. It will be even slower, if one doesn't properly dispose of it when finished using it as it may leave the instance running which can be observed in Windows Task Manager.

Comment: You may find it quite slow in Debug, but the release compiled exe "should" be quicker